# Overload operator>> for std::pair<int, int>

Tags: c++, boost, std, argument-dependent-lookup

I am trying to use `boost::lexical_cast` on a `std::pair<int, int>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace my
{
  // When my_pair is a user defined type, this program compiles
  // and runs without any problems.
  // When declaring my_pair as an alias of std::pair<int, int>,
  // it fails to compile

  /*
  struct my_pair
  {
      int first;
      int second;
  };
  */

  using my_pair = std::pair<int, int>;

  std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, my_pair& pair)
  {
    stream >> pair.first;
    stream >> std::skipws;
    stream >> pair.second;
    return stream;
  }
}

int main()
{
  my::my_pair p = boost::lexical_cast<my::my_pair>("10 10");
  std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

If I understand right, in order to make ADL work, the operator>> has to be in the same namespace as my_pair, so std.

Doing so, would result in undefined behavior, because I would be adding functions to the namespace std.

I would like to avoid inheritance, as in `struct my_pair : std::pair<int, int>`.

What could be the solution to this problem?

I am using clang++-3.6 on OS X.

Comment: @KirilKirov "I would like to avoid inheritance". The alias is not a type. It's an alias

Comment: @sehe - o, I didn't notice, that it's `using` and not a real type. I was really missing something :)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of ADL-hooking on the value to stream, you could overload  on the stream (tagging it in some way):

```
int main() {
    std::map<int, std::string> standback { { 42, "I'm gonna try" }, { 1729, "science" } };

    streaming::tag_ostream out = std::cout;

    for (auto& entry : standback)
        out << entry << "\n";
}
```

This way, you can ADL-hook on a namespace that is under your control. You can make the tagging more generic (think `auto out = streaming::tag(std::cout)`).

Now, a simple implementation of that could look like

```
namespace streaming {

    template <typename T>
    struct tag : std::reference_wrapper<T> {
        using std::reference_wrapper<T>::reference_wrapper;
    };

    using tag_ostream = tag<std::ostream>;

    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    static inline tag_ostream operator<<(tag_ostream os, std::pair<T1, T2> const& p) {
        os.get() << "std::pair{" << p.first << ", " << p.second  << "}";
        return os;
    }

    template <typename Other>
    static inline tag_ostream operator<<(tag_ostream os, Other const& o) {
        os.get() << o;
        return os;
    }
}
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f4e71a537c62e44)**, which prints:

```
std::pair{42, I'm gonna try}
std::pair{1729, science}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Doing so, would result in undefined behavior, because I would be adding functions to the namespace std.
>
> I would like to avoid inheritance, as in struct my_pair : std::pair.

I wanted to say "inheritance", but you dismiss it ...

You could use encapsulation, simply adding another strong type over `std::pair<int,int>` (but in such a trivial case, you may be better off with the custom structure - your commented code):

```
struct my_pair
{
    std::pair<int,int> value;
    // TODO: add any access interface here
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, my_pair& pair)
{
    stream >> pair.value.first;
    stream >> std::skipws;
    stream >> pair.value.second;
    return stream;
}
```

Infact, you probably *should* do this, because std::pair is more of a building block, not something that should be used to represent semantic information (and not something that should be dirrectly printable to a stream).

Comment: I see no reason not to avoid inheritance. `my_pair` _is-a_ `std::pair<int,int>` and this is precisely what inheritance is for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit,The only reason I can see for inheritance is in OP's question: "I would like to avoid inheritance, as in struct my_pair : std::pair.".

Comment: Fortunately I do not feel restricted by silly and unexplained cosntraints: this _is_ the best approach to solve this problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

I know you said that you didn't want this, but I definitely *would* use inheritance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

namespace my
{
   struct my_pair : std::pair<int, int> {};

   std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& stream, my_pair& pair)
   {
      stream >> pair.first;
      stream >> std::skipws;
      stream >> pair.second;
      return stream;
   }
}

int main()
{
    my::my_pair p = boost::lexical_cast<my::my_pair>("10 10");
    std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8ce9dc456a1a8ce))

Your `my::my_pair` literally *is-a* `std::pair<int, int>`; you just need it to be a distinct type in your own namespace. This is what inheritance is for.

I'm just leaving this here to show how easy it is to do and explain why I think you should do it.