# C++:An elegant way to print all pairs in a list

Tags: c++, list, stl, std-pair

I define a lists like this:

```
std::list < pair<string, int> > token_list;
```

I want to print out all list elements, so I write it out:

```
std::copy(std::begin(token_list),
          std::end(token_list),
          std::ostream_iterator<pair<string, int> >(std::cout, " "));
```

But I've been getting this error:

```
error 2679:binary "<<"the operator (or unacceptable conversion) that accepts the right operand oftype (or unacceptable)
```

in Visual Studio. How can I fix it,or is there any other way to print out all pairs in a list?

Comment: [This shows how to define an **input** operator for a `std::pair`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30642290/1171191). You need an **output** operator, but the same special conditions apply.

Comment: Consider using `std::vector` instead of `std::list`. It wil generally perform much better on modern hardware.

Answer (score 4):

You 're getting this error because there is no overloaded `operator <<` for `std::pair`.

However, printing a list of pairs is not that hard. I don't know if this is an `elegant way to print all pairs in a list` but all you need is a simple for loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>> token_list = { {"token0", 0}, {"token1", 1}, {"token2", 2} };

    for ( const auto& token : token_list )
        std::cout << token.first << ", " << token.second << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You are needlessly copying all the pairs in that loop. Use `for (const auto& token : token_list)`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yep, fixed it.