# overloading ostream_iterator for custom types for printing

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> PAIR;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PAIR& rec)
{
    os << "(" << rec.first << ", " << rec.second << ")";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    vector<PAIR > v{ {1,3},{2,3}, {1,0}, {1,5} };
    auto x1 = v;
    cout << "v: ";
    //std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator< PAIR >(cout, ", "));
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        cout << v[i]<<",";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**
v: (1, 3),(2, 3),(1, 0),(1, 5),

I would like to get similar output with commented line
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator< PAIR >(cout, ", "));

But I am getting the following error.
binary 'operator' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'type' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Above error is not comprehensible to me. Any help or pointers is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30642133/overload-operator-for-stdpairint-int) (not sure if it's considered a duplicate though). [Your code compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/1MGv85eo1) when I use `struct PAIR {int first; int second};` instead of `typedef pair<int, int> PAIR;`

Comment: @Kevin  Thank you. I see that changing typedef to struct is working fine as we want. Why is  struct PAIR {int first; int second}; working,  where as typedef pair<int, int> PAIR; is failing to compile?

Comment: Because of [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). The `std::ostream_iterator` code can't find your `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::pair<int, int>& rec)` function. Adding it to the same namespace as the types in the function would normally work, but adding to the `std` namespace is undefined behavior, so there isn't really a way to do what you want beyond using a custom type.